# CDI deployment failure:WELD-001414 Bean name is ambiguous

Tags: java, maven, cdi, glassfish-4, weld

I have an application, which has multiple modules and various dependencies. When I deploy the application on Glassfish 4, I am getting error:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001414 Bean name is ambiguous. 
Name    JerseyClassAnalyzer resolves to beans: [Managed Bean [class org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer] 
with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any], Managed Bean 
[class org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer] 
with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any]]
```

What can be the cause? I saw already topics about this and the solution was to edit the annotation but this is not my `EJB`, just a dependency. How can I avoid this exception?

I am using Java EE 6 with JDK 1.7 and Glassfish 4.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Glassfish is already having Jerseys libraries packaged for you, so you need add `provided` scope into your Maven `pom.xml` as stated in the [docs](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html#dependencies).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you are using any Jersey specific feature, you will need to depend on Jersey directly.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you by any chance packaging the Jersey specific libraries in your EAR file. I believe glassfish does provide the Jersey libraries and you do not need to package them.

Comment: That's right. A dependency packages jersey specific libraries and that was cause. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two @Named bean class with the same name.